# не корректно прекращается css анимация

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Добавляю анимацию с этой библиотеки https://github.com/daneden/animate.css, в хендлере по окончанию анимации, убираю с обьекта класс с анимацей, но она прекращается не корректно, и очень часто обьект самопроизвольно начинает анимироваться если водить курсосром по его div зоне.

```
<script>
          $( ".leftTop" ).mouseover (function() {
            const element =  document.querySelector('.Projects')
            element.classList.add('animated', 'flip')
            element.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
            element.classList.remove('animated', 'flip');})
          });
</script>
```

По идее, насколько я понимаю, зашел курсор в зону, началась анимация, проигралась, хенддлер уловил конец и я удалил класс с ней и все, а так до следующего захода курсора на нужную область, но выходит криво.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Осмелюсь предположить, что всё выглядит примерно так.
И при наведение получается следующее:
Наведение курсора -> Воспроизведение анимации -> Двигаем курсор -> Снова анимация.

Если да, то проблема в том, что блок `.Projects` при анимации "увеличивается" и попадает под курсор, тем самым отдав команду js, что обработчик `mouseover` "обнулился" и анимация начинается повторно, при движение мышки.

```js
$(".leftTop").mouseover(function() {
  const element = document.querySelector('.Projects');
  element.classList.add('animated', 'flip');
  element.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    element.classList.remove('animated', 'flip');
  })
});
```

```css
.leftTop {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background: gray;
}

.Projects {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="leftTop">наведи</div>
<div class="Projects"></div>
```

Я предлагаю следующий вариант, самый простой как по мне:
Использовать одно интересное свойство, во время анимации, для этого нужно внести изменение в CSS.

```js
$(".leftTop").mouseover(function() {
  const element = document.querySelector('.Projects');
  element.classList.add('animated', 'flip');
  element.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    element.classList.remove('animated', 'flip');
  })
});
```

```css
.leftTop {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  background: gray;
}

.Projects {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

/* ↓↓↓ */
.Projects.animated {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="leftTop">наведи</div>
<div class="Projects"></div>
```

> **`pointer-events: none;`**
>   Элемент не может быть целью (target) cобытий мыши; тем не менее, целью событий мыши могут быть его потомки, если их pointer-events имеет какое-либо другое значение. В этом случае события мыши вызовут ожидаемое срабатывание обработчиков на этом родительском элементе на пути к/от потомк(у)/(а) во время фазы захвата/всплытия.

Источник: [pointer-events - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Хороший, грамотный ответ. Я тоже использую, но в svg это свойство `pointer-evtnts="none"` Лучше наверное объяснить автору вопроса своими словами - события мыши,- клик, наведение проходят насквозь верхнего элемента к нижнему

Comment: Спасибо, очень хороший ответ.